# CSS overriding a selector with a background colour works, but using no colour doesn't

Tags: html, css

I have a particular css setup - not really ideal but the "main" element selector is dedicated to having this `background-color: white;` and I can't change this.

I can edit the rest and add more css if necessary. Below is a minimised example of the issue using `div` in place of `body` so I can show both versions in one snippet.

I apply a background image with my `div` element and then I need the `main` element within it to have a different background-color (i.e. overrule the `main` selector)

So I used an id `#num1` with the different background colour applied. Works fine.

On the second example, why does `none` not work? Why does a colour application overrule but `none` just reverts back to the white colour?

```css
main{
  background-color: white;
}

div{
  background-image: url(https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg);
  height: 100px;
}

#num1{
  background-color: orange;
}

#num2{
  background-color: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>Hello</header>
  <main>
    <p id="num1">Some Text</p>
  </main>
</div>

<hr/>

<div>
  <header>Hello</header>
  <main>
    <p id="num2">Some Text</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: because it's in invalid value (inspect the code). Use transparent or initial

Comment: if you can add more CSS why you cannot simply add more CSS to main to override it's background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`none` isn't a colour, it is an image (or lack of one) and a valid value for the `background-image` property.

`transparent` is a colour.

---

You might be getting confused because the `background` shorthand property will default to `transparent` if you don't specify a colour and `none` if you don't specify an image making `background: none` equivalent to `background-image: none; background-color: transparent`.

---

That said the element with the `id` `num2` doesn't have a background colour specified, so it is already `transparent`.

There is no colour you can set on it that will make it punch a hole through the background colour of the `main` element it is inside.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, makes sense - seems because main is stuck like that, I'll never be able to get back to the background image!